# Redundant Exchange email addresses in AD

Tags: exchange-2003

Our organization recently underwent a name change and with it a new domain structure. We were supporting the old email addresses for a while but have mandated that the old addresses be retired. Now the old addresses are causing an issue with our mail routing.

How can I on-mass remove the old @domain.com addresses without going through each AD account individually?

Comment: What kind of isse?

Answer (score 1):

[Admodify](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996216%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx) from Microsoft is your friend.

Specifically:

[image]

[Here](http://www.msexchange.org/articles/ADModify-Change-Exchange-Specific-AD-User-Attributes.html) are more instructions on how to make bulk changes using admodify.

Answer (score 1):

If all your addresses were being generated by recipient policy, just change the recipient policy and trigger the RUS to "Rebuild".

This is one of the reasons that I refuse to manually add addresses to individual recipients. If someone needs an "alias" I create group with the appropriate alias / address and put the user into the group. To my mind, all addresses in the Organization should be generated by recipient policy.

Comment: While it was generated by recipient policy, the policy was set on the previous domain and the accounts were migrated across to the new domain -- the policy doesn't exist any longer and the addresses are now "legacy". I think the ADModify app will solve the issue.